# How to use a book press for veneering?

Tags: veneer, clamps, boxes

I've been experimenting with veneering for box-making and other small scale items.  I'm not having much luck with the "PVA glue + iron" method.  Based on a few experiments it seems to work for me part of the time, but it seems tedious and a bit variable.

I purchased an inexpensive "book press":

[image: Vevor book press]

My plan is to make two platens out of MDF, laminating 2 pieces of 3/4" for each.

When veneering, I will sandwich the piece(s) being veneered between those two platens with a piece of waxed paper on each side.

My concerns are twofold:

- distribution of pressure across the two platens, particular with veneer that likely doesn't have a uniform thickness.
- where does glue squeeze out go?

The approach I'm ideating on is to introduce a slight "crown" in one of the platens using two pieces of tape arranged in a cross shape (or even a star shape):

[image: diagram]

My thought it that the pressure would be applied first along the the "tape lines", and as pressure is cranked up, the squeeze out would seep out the lower areas.

How should I arrange this?  Should I introduce a soft, slightly compressible material (like cloth) into the veneer sandwich?

Any sage advice to share?

Comment: I guess I've always thought the recommended way to do veneer was to use contact cement and a roller.

Comment: I have a bit of experience with that approach on melamine for cabinetry, but I’ve never quite understood why the same approach doesn’t seem to be used for veneering hardwood.  Moisture and movement?

Comment: X-y problem.....

Comment: @bowlturner, the traditional way is using a protein glue (hot hide glue, Scotch glue) on a toothed ground. These days there are multiple glueing options, including contact adhesive, epoxy and other conventional adhesives used wet, and the PVA + ironing method.

Comment: I'd worry that the edges of the tape might telegraph/impress themselves into the veneer. And since the press's platen is presumably reasonably flat, force is already distributed; crowned cauls are generally used to carry force inward from edge clamping. I'd say try a sample as it is, or possibly with leather to help the platen and platform conform to any slight non-flatness in your workpiece, and see if you need to do anything else. Note that the modern solution for even pressure across veneered surfaces is a vacuum bag, and as noted there are glue alternatives like contact cement.